# Prevent searches less than 4 characters

Tags: search

When users search for 1,2 or 3 characters this puts a lot of strain on the database. A malicious user could search for 1,2 or 3 characters and bring my site down to its knees.

I presume I could use some Jquery code to prevent users entering less than 4 characters when searching.

```
   <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">                             
                            <input type="text" value="<?php _e( 'search', 'swagger' ); ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e( 'search', 'swagger' ); ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e( 'search', 'swagger' ); ?>';}" name="s" id="s" />          
                        </form>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: "A malicious user" would also know how to easily bypass this - if you want to protect  your server - check on the server-side !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pattern` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) to ask for at least 3 characters:

```
<input pattern=".{3,}">
```

But if your database dies just because someone searches for a three letter word … you have other problems than search. Optimize your database instead, or find another solution. A simple search, even dozens per minute should not be a problem.

To catch empty searches, see my article on WPEngineer: [Fix Empty Searches](http://wpengineer.com/2162/fix-empty-searches/)

Comment: ok this works but it doesn't prevent users entering nothing and pressing enter

Comment: @MarioLorenzo See my update.